# Evaluate the indefinite integral $\int\frac{9x+6}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm d x$

Tags: calculus

This is my work so far I was not able to get the correct answer.

$$\int\frac{9x+6}{x^2+1} \,\mathrm{d}x = \int\frac{9x}{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x + \int\frac6{x^2+1} \,\mathrm{d}x$$

$$= 9 \int\frac x{x^2+1} \,\mathrm{d}x + 6 \int\frac1{x^2+1} \,\mathrm{d}x $$

$$u = x^2+1\implies \mathrm{d}u = 2x\,\mathrm{d}x  $$

$$9\cdot\frac12 \int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}+ 6\int \frac1{(2)^2+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x$$

$$\frac92 \ln(x^2+1) + 3 \arctan\left(\frac x3\right)$$

Comment: What is the correct answer?

Comment: thats what im asking the last line is what i came up with

Comment: @Teh Rod thanks for your help

Comment: You've got $\displaystyle\int \frac 1 {x^2+1} \, dx.$  Why did you change that to $\displaystyle\int \frac 1 {2^2+x^2} \, dx \text{?}$ That doesn't make sense. Just recall that $\displaystyle \int \frac 1 {x^2+1} \,dx = \arctan x + \text{constant}. \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in $\displaystyle\int \frac 6 {x^2+1} \, \mathrm{d}x$ so the integral of that is just $6\tan^{-1}x+C$